# Mostrar mensaje resultado no encontrados

Tags: jquery

Estimados quisiera mostrar un mensaje de resultados no encontrados si es que en el archivo JSON no se encuentra el criterio de búsqueda, dejo el código que tengo donde puedo añadir ese linea de código es un mensaje de no resultados si no se encuentra ningún termino de búsqueda espero se  entienda y gracias

```js
function Cargardata(count) {
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

  $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
    var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

    var dataCounter = 0;

    $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
        if ((dataCounter < count) && ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1))) {
          output += '<li>';
          output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
          output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
          output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
          output += '</li>';
          dataCounter +=1;
        }
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $('content').html(output);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque simplemente primero preguntas si `data.data` tiene elementos, si tiene pues geneneras el contenido, de lo contrario, generas un solo diciendo que no hay data:

```
function Cargardata(count) {
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

  $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
    var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

    var dataCounter = 0;    
    if(data.data.length > 0)
    {
        $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
            if ((dataCounter < count) && ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1))) {
              output += '<li>';
              output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
              output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
              output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
              output += '</li>';
              dataCounter +=1;
            }
        });
    }
    else{
      output += '<li><strong>No se encontro resultados</strong></li>';
    }
    output += '</ul>';
    $('content').html(output);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es imprimir algo, cuando retorna 0 podrías usar:

```
$.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
    if ( data.length == 0 ) {
        console.log("No hay datos!")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

bueno estimados no funciono el código, no se por que el anterior código se cambio a  mi me funciona bien el que tengo y con la modificación que se puso me dejo de funcionar en este código a mi me anda bien

```js
function Cargardata(count) {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

    $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul id="resultado">';
        var dataToShow = data.data.slice(0, count);
        $.each(dataToShow, function(i, item) {
            if ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
                output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
                output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('content').html(output);
    });

}
```